# Data source for DevExpress GridControl with paging, sorting, filtering, grouping

Tags: sql-server, winforms, devexpress, datasource, .net-6.0

What data source can we use so that we can get data from SQL Server and display it in a DevExpress GridControl (in WinForms)? It needs to work with .NET 6 and provide automatic **paging, sorting, filtering and grouping** at the SQL query level.

What we had when we used .NET Framework 4.7 was a `LinqServerModeSource` connected to a `DataContext` table:

```
using System.Data.Linq;

linqServerModeSource.QueryableSource = new DataContext(connectionString).GetTable(typeof(Persons));
gridPersons.DataSource = linqServerModeSource;
```

but in .NET 6 the namespace `System.Data.Linq` does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [EntityServerModeSource](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.Data.Linq.EntityServerModeSource?utm_source=visualstudio&utm_medium=DXHelpAssistant&utm_campaign=onlinehelp&v=21.2) in conjunction with Entity Framework Core [DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext?view=efcore-6.0) and [DbSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1?view=efcore-6.0):

```
entityServerModeSource.QueryableSource = myDbContext.PersonsDbSet;
entityServerModeSource.KeyExpression = "Id";
entityServerModeSource.Reload();
gridPersons.DataSource = entityServerModeSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an OData API endpoint for the DevExpress component. LINQ/EF magic will then transpile the OData queries from DefExpress to SQL.

The return type of the controller action will be `IQueryable` and IIRC you need to add the `[Queryable]` attribute -- but webAPI is such a moving target that they've probably changed it all since I last did it.

The `IQueryable` in questin will be an entity set (or a LINQ expression on entity sets) in your db context. If your basic query is quite complicated then you might prefer to make a view for it and map that to an entity set.

This all means that the query for your underlying dataset is known at compile time...